# Different unicodes for same string in java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, utf

As per my knowledge i know unicode character means every letter has an unique code.

In my database i have set utl8.

Here, i am saving a string (ఉత్తరప్రదేశ్)  directly into the database in java.Then it is saved as

```
&#3081;&#3108;&#3149;&#3108;&#3120;&#3114;
&#3149;&#3120;&#3110;&#3143;&#3126;&#3149;
```

But the same string i saved in database using

```
escapeUnicode(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("here string"));


public String escapeUnicode(String input) {
   StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(input.length());
   Formatter f = new Formatter(b);
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
      if (c < 128) {
        b.append(c);
      } else {
        f.format("\\u%04x", (int) c);
      }
     }
   return b.toString();
}
```

It is generating unicode as

```
\u0c09\u0c24\u0c4d\u0c24\u0c30\u0c2a\u0c4d\u0c30\u0c26\u0c47\u0c36\u0c4d
```

Both are displaying in browser correctly.Why they both are generating different unicodes ?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are *not* different numbers…

- 3081 = 0c09 = ఉ = TELUGU LETTER U
- 3108 = 0c24 = త = TELUGU LETTER TA
- 3149 = 0c4d = ్ = TELUGU SIGN VIRAMA

… and so on.

Two different ways to represent the same [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

The first are decimal numbers (base 10). The second are [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers (base 16).

When using a class such as [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), sometimes it helps to read the documentation. Then you might understand why you pasted `f.format("\\u%04x"` into your code.

Tip: If you have a Mac, download the [UnicodeChecker](http://www.earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/) app to see both decimal and hex numbers for each character defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).